# How to change the icon using a xml variable?

Tags: xml, google-maps, xml-parsing

I do not know javascript and I'm stuck in trying to bring up two different icons depending on a variable of xml file in a google map.
Can you please give me your opinion to understand where it does not work.

I thank you in advance

```
var lat =46.686111; //latitude par défaut
var lng=1.875278;// longitude par défaut
var homeLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng (lat,lng); // coordonnées par défaut
var infowindow;
var marker;
var map;

function initialize () {
var myOptions={
center :homeLatLng, //centre de la carte
zoom : 6, // niveau de zoom pour toute la France
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
 //type de Map
};
 map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById ("map-canvas"), myOptions); //init de la carte

downloadUrl("../mda/xml/points.xml", function(data) {
      var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var marker = createMarker(markers[i].getAttribute("nom"), latlng);
               }
     });
}


function createMarker(nom, latlng) {

var statut =[];
statut['pro']= '../image/icongac.png';
statut['conso']='../image/iconact.png';
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map, icon: statut   
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: nom});
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    return marker;
  }  
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);
```

but it does not work
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
img = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../image/icongac.png');

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos,
    icon: img,
});
```

You have to use MarkerImage function to define which icon the marker should have.